# MONTHNAME in Portuguese MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date

I´ve got a huge query (In a PHP file) that gives me a monthname from some dates:

```
CASE A.STATUS
WHEN 'Cancel' THEN LEFT(MONTHNAME(DT_CANCEL),3)
WHEN 'About to cancel' THEN LEFT(MONTHNAME(DATA_REGISTER),3)

END AS MONTH_CANCEL,
```

Is there a way to insert my language inline with MONTHANAME?

Something like:

```
WHEN 'Cancel' THEN SET LANGUAGE Portuguese LEFT(MONTHNAME(DT_CANCEL),3)
```

I don´t want to write case for eveymonth to transform 'Dec' to 'Dez' and so on, this will take too long.

Comment: Check [10.15 MySQL Server Locale Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately in MySQL this cannot be done dynamically within a query.

From the documentation :

> The language used for the month name is controlled by the `lc_time_names` system variable.

You need a separate SQL command to change the setting :

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_PT';
SELECT MONTHNAME('2018-12-28') AS 'Month';
```

The value of the `lc_time_names` persists for the lifetime of the MySQL session.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following query before you run your query:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_PT';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was racking my brain with a chart where the months were in Spanish. Solved my problem.

```
try{    
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
    $conn->exec("SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR'");
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error! " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```